# Google form regex email validation excluding some domain

Tags: regex, forms, google-forms, email-validation

I'd like to restrict to non-private emails a field.

I'm using the regex

`^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$`

and I want to blacklist gmail and icloud domains.

Following the [RE2 Syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax?sjid=300485985710569298-EU#ascii) I tried with

`^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[^(gmail)|(icloud)][a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$`

but the blacklist instruction `[^(gmail)|(icloud)]` doesn't work: it matches any character instead of the entire word

`^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@((?!gmail|icloud).)[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$` works in a non-RE2 environment.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: RE2 does not support lookarounds, and forbidding "like" domains is not feasible enough.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to exclude gmail and icloud (for example), not "some domains like them"

Comment: It is impractical to write such patterns, they do not scale and are error-prone, and they are not even readable. With no lookaround support, you'd better use other ways to implement this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can this be translated in a script maybe?

Comment: There are solutions to translate `^(?:(word).)*$` like patterns, but I have not seen any for  `^(?:(word|anotherword).)*$`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you very much, I'll learn JS to make a script, I think it's the only way

Comment: I do not believe that an apps script will work in this case because it will not run until the form is submitted.

Answer (score -2):

Add a negative *look-ahead* where the domain text starts.

Additionally,

- Simplify the `a-zA-Z0-9_` to `\w`, and `0-9` to `\d`
- Use *"case-insensitive match"* mode, `(?i)`

```
(?i)^[\w.%+-]+@(?!gmail|icloud)[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$
```

---

Edit

> *"... I want to blacklist gmail and icloud domains.*
>
> *Following the [RE2 Syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax?sjid=300485985710569298-EU#ascii) ..."*

So, the *look-around* syntax is not supported, it's under the *"escape sequences"* table, in the link you've provided.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I'm afraid it doesn't works with google forms cause it's based on RE2. It can be done by adding a script into the document but I don't know anything about JS too :)

Comment: lookarounds are not supported in RE2: https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/WhyRE2

Comment: @MrShane, yes it's in my answer, with a link.